# Why use COALESCE() in sql statement?

Tags: sql, mysql, coalesce

I'm refactoring some old code and stumbled upon this named query
(It's using hibernate on top of mysql):

```
delete F from
    foo F
inner join user DU on F.user_id = DU.id
where
(COALESCE(:userAlternateId,null) is null or DU.alternate_id like :userAlternateId )
    and ( COALESCE(:fooId,null) is null or F.foo_id like :fooId )
    and (
        ( COALESCE(:fromUpdated,null) is null or F.updated_at>=:fromUpdated )
        and ( COALESCE(:toUpdated,null) is null or F.updated_at<=:toUpdated )
)
```

I don't understand why this `COALESCE` is being used in this fashion:
`COALESCE(:userAlternateId,null) is null`

Is this a performance hack or does it make the query database independent or ...?

btw `userAlternateId` is a string/varchar, other id's are longs and `from-to` are dates

Comment: @slugster he says MySQL (first para) - unless this is Hibernate HQL?

Comment: Ahh of course... i was too busy looking at the SQL to notice that. COALESCEing a null to null kind of distracted me.

Comment: It's quite possible that it just ended up that way through changes happening due to experiments or fixes and it moved from something like `COALESCE(:val, -1) = -1` to `COALESCE(:val, null) is null` which pointless, you can see how it could have happened.

Comment: @Jon Hanna yes, I think it must be something like that, it just doesn't make sense otherwise, I'll refactor it away to something more readable, thnx

Comment: After all, if it all was perfect, you wouldn't be refactoring it :)

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any reason for COALESCE being used this way.

Following statement is equivalent

```
DELETE  F 
FROM    foo F
        INNER JOIN User DU on F.user_id = DU.id
WHERE   (:userAlternateId IS NULL OR DU.alternate_id LIKE :userAlternateId)
        AND (:fooId IS NULL OR F.foo_id LIKE :fooId)
        AND (:fromUpdated IS NULL OR F.updated_at >= :fromUpdated)
        AND (:toUpdated IS NULL OR F.updated_at <= :toUpdated)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, thinking about this more, I'm betting on what I suggested in the comment on the question. Either it's auto-generated code, and its an artefact of the way the code generating that code has to handle more general issues than the particular case it's dealing with here, or it's an artefact of someone moving from something more reasonable like `COALESCE(:userAlternateId, "not set") = "not set"` to `COALESCE(:userAlternateId,null) is null`, which while not very sensible, is something that you can see how someone could get from A to B.